# Morphism of schemes such that the image contains every generic point of an irreducible component

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes.  When the image $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$, we say that $f$ is *dominant.*

No doubt, dominant morphisms pop up all over the place and have an important role in birational geometry.  But a lot of the time it seems to me like the property we are *really* interested in is that $f(X)$ contains all the generic points of irreducible components of $Y$.  See, for example, the stacks project entry on Dominant Morphisms [Stacks 01RI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RI#:%7E:text=A%20morphism%20f%20%3A%20X%20%5Cto,a%20dense%20subset%20of%20S.&text=Let%20f%20%3A%20X%20%5Cto%20S,f%2C%20then%20f%20is%20dominant.), which is entirely devoted to the question of when these properties coincide.  In geometric situations, like when our schemes have finitely many irreducible components, or when our morphisms are quasi-compact, the concepts coincide.  But in general, dominance is a much weaker property.

Let's for now denote by $(*)$ the property of a morphism that its image contains all the generic points of the irreducible components of the target (aka codimension $0$ points aka maximal points).

A couple questions:

(1) Does $(*)$ have an agreed upon name in the literature? Is it interesting in its own right? More/less useful than dominance in general scheme theory?

(2) Is there a historical reason for the prevailing definition of dominance? Some thoughts: in EGA dominance is introduced along with other purely topological properties of morphisms, like being open, closed, surjective.  Meanwhile $(*)$ can be expressed in purely topological terms, but if we even want compositions of $(*)$ morphisms to be stable under composition then we need to restrict to *spectral* spaces.  So in some sense dominance makes sense as a purely topological property but $(*)$ heavily depends on respecting structure sheaves.